# Add styles for a new page Template

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am new to SAP Commerce and Spartacus. I have created a new Page Template, Content Page and defined some slots in that.

I have used the existing component(s) in the content slot(s).

Now, How and where can I add the custom styles for the new Page Template?

Answer (score 0):

Would you please refer to the documentation regarding Component Styles?

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/css-architecture/#style-library

> Since Spartacus components are built and distributed in libraries, component styles cannot be used. These styles would be pre-processed and baked into the component library. This means that the CSS rules would not be optional, nor would they be easily customizable.

> Instead, component styles are delivered optionally in the styles library. You can use those styles, extend them, or completely skip them and build your CSS rules from scratch. The contract between the style library and the component library is done through the (unique) component selector.

Best regards,
Jerry

Comment: Thanks Jerry! I have already gone through this doc. Can you please explain me using an example? like, creating a new custom CMS page and applying the styles there.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I found only one solution is to add global styles and use grids to make proper layout.